# How to create pentaho cde dashbord with convert to pdf button?

Tags: pdf, phantomjs, pentaho

i just want to create a pentaho cde dashboard with convert to pdf button. when i click the button the dashboard should be downloaded as pdf format. i searched couple of blogs they suggested to use sparkl and phantomjs to do so. but currently sparkl is not available in pentaho marketplace. there is any alternative way to do this conversion? please help me.

Thanks in advance,
Kannas

Answer (score 0):

some time ago a customer of my company asked the same and I was in the same situation as you, phantomjs works, but the customers asked for something a little more complicated, they wanted the graphics to export it will stay with the state they had , That is to say when filtering they will be exported to PDF as well. After giving up with phantomjs, I started looking for other technologies to do this, and so I found the following

1. jspdf.js
2. html2canvas.js
3. html2canvas.svg.js
4. rgbcolor.js
5. stackBlur.js
6. canvg.js
7. addhtml.js

I explain what I did, create a new document using jspdf, then add the html page to a temporary canvas with canvg.js, html2canvas.js, html2canvas.svg.js, you have to keep in mind that the graphics are svg, and the treatment to add it to the canvas is different than create and then export it to PDF
I create a component of Pentaho, that you pass the html object that you want to export and export only that, I can not give you the code because it is reserved right for my company, but at some point I will create this component again to share it with the community, Regards